# How do I get the value of a dropdown in a pug file?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a pug file that dynamically populates a dropdown from a list of objects (customers), but I can't seem to get the value that is currently selected from it.
Here is the code:

```
select(name="customerDropdown", id="customerDropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle")
    each customer in customers 
      option=customer

  script.
    var el = document.getElementById('customerDropdown');
    var strCustomer = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
```

strCustomer doesn't seem to hold any value after this. Any help apprecited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code and see how it works on your side:

```
- var customers = ['John','Maria','Nicolas']
select(name="customerDropdown", id="customerDropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle")
    each customer in customers 
      option=customer
  
script.
  var $customerDropdown = document.getElementById('customerDropdown');
  
  var getSelectedCustomer = function() {
    return $customerDropdown.options[$customerDropdown.selectedIndex].text
  }
  
  $customerDropdown.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    alert('new value: ' + getSelectedCustomer())
  });
  
  alert(getSelectedCustomer())
```

It should alert the first value in the select box (`John`) when the app is launched and later on when you change the select option - it should alert the selected one. E.g. if you select `Nicolas` it should alert (`new value: Nicolas`)

Hope this will give you the idea on how to handle select element.